# Backbone.js with Handlebars.js not rendering options

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I'm building my first Backbone.js app and want to use Handlebars to insert my data.
I've got the backbone.View rendering ok but the {{ variables }} are not being replaced with the data I pass in.

This is my view

```
OrderRow = Backbone.View.extend({

template: Handlebars.compile(
    '<div class="orderContainer">' +
        '<p class="row-top-container left">{{id}}</p>' +
        '<p class="row-top-container right">{{time_stamp}}</p>' + 
        '<p class="row-top-container right">{{queue_time}}</p><br />' +
        '<p class="items-contaier">{{items}}</p>' +
    '</div>'
),

initialize: function(){
    console.log("options used: " + this.options.sayHello );
    this.render();
},

render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.options));
    return this;
}
});


    var data = {
        id:657543,
        name:"name"
    }

    var row = new OrderRow({ el: $('.row'), options:data });
```

And this is the DOM after the view's been rendered

[image: DOM structure after View rendered]

Does anyone know what I'm missing?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. Backbone no longer automatically sets `this.options` in views so your code will break when you upgrade Backbone. You can solve this by doing it yourself in `initialize`:

   ```
   initialize: function(options) {
       this.options = options;
       //...
   }
   ```
2. You have multiple `.row` elements so saying `el: $('.row')` will bind the view to all of them (depending on the Backbone version) and that could cause strange things to happen. You'd be better off binding one view to each `<li>` using the `id` attributes on the `<li>`s:

   ```
   new OrderRow({ el: '#152293', ... });
   ```
3. You're not feeding your template what you think you are. You're passing the data to your view in the `options` option:

   ```
   new OrderRow({ ..., options: data });
   ```

   so that `data` will end up in `this.options.options` inside the view and that means that you want to say:

   ```
   this.$el.html(this.template(this.options.options))
   ```

   or use `this.options = options.options` in `initialize` and keep using `this.options` elsewhere.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/9w3AW/

Wrapping your `data` in a Backbone model would probably make more sense though.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I'm still getting my head around backbone.js

Just one thing, 
I'm passing a model containing the data now as you suggested but I'm only getting the 'id' from the model. I'm not getting the 'time_stamp', 'queue_time' or 'items'. 
Why is that?

Again, thanks!

Comment: A model will have an `id` property that Handlebars will see, the others will be inside its `attributes` property. You'd usually say `model.toJSON()` to get the data for the template.